# Calling Raspberry Pi temp sensor, invalid syntax when calling driver as bash script

Tags: syntax, raspberry-pi, temperature

I'm currently putting together a temperature sensor for my Raspberry Pi and ran into this issue. In order to run the driver designated in the code, I had to run it was a shell command. I'm having a difficult time figuring out why my syntax is incorrect.

**Code:**

```
def read_dht22( PiPin ):
        output = subprocess.check_output([shell=True], ['/home/pi/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/Adafruit__DHT_Driver", "2302", str(PiPin)])
```

**Error:**

```
sudo python scr6.py
  File "scr6.py", line 31
    output = subprocess.check_output([shell=True], ['/home/pi/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/Adafruit_DHT_Driver', '2302', str(PiPin)])
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Error Prior to Adding shell=True**

```
sudo python scr5.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scr5.py", line 46, in <module>
    temp_c, temp_f = read_dht22(4)
  File "scr5.py", line 31, in read_dht22
    output = subprocess.check_output(["/home/pi/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/Adafruit_DHT_Driver", "2302", str(PiPin)])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your syntax error:

```
def read_dht22( PiPin ):
    output = subprocess.check_output(["/home/pi/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/Adafruit__DHT_Driver", "2302", str(PiPin)], shell=True)
```